# How to use WebApi along with MVC 5 in Student - course model - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api, solid-principles

I have experience of developing ASP.NET-MVC application and learning WebApi very recently. I understood that action method in API are HTTP, hence can directly the resulting model. I am also aware that I can use MVC along with WebApi, my struggling to understand where these two fit together and where should I use WebAPI and where not in single MVC-based application; taking example from following; my 2nd question is where I apply MVC and WebApi

[image]

### Student Model

```
 public partial class Student
{
    public Student()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### Course Model

```
 public partial class Course
{
    public Course()
    {
        this.StudentCourses = new HashSet<StudentCourse>();
    }

    public int CourseID { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<StudentCourse> StudentCourses { get; set; }
}
```

### StudentCourseModel

```
public partial class StudentCourse
{
    [Key]
    public int StudentCourseID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentID { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("Course")]
    public int CourseID { get; set; }

    public virtual Course Course { get; set; }
    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

### Function Logic of App

```
 public class processData
{
    public void addStudent()
    {
        using(var db = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var _student1 = new Student { Name = "waqas" };

            db.Students.Add(_student1);

            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Press Any Key to Read Students....");
        Console.ReadLine();

        readStudents();
    }


    public void readStudents()
    {
        using (var db2 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            List<Student> _studentRead = new List<Student>();

            _studentRead = (from _student in db2.Students
                                .Include(r => r.StudentCourses.Select(sc => sc.Course))
                                select _student).ToList();

        }
    }

    public void CreateCourse()
    {
        using(var db3 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var _course1 = new Course { Title = "Math"};
            var _course2 = new Course { Title = "English" };
            var _course3 = new Course { Title = "computing" };
            var _course4 = new Course { Title = "Science" };

            db3.Courses.Add(_course1);
            db3.Courses.Add(_course2);
            db3.Courses.Add(_course3);
            db3.Courses.Add(_course4);

            db3.SaveChanges();
        }
    }

    public void ReadCourses()
    {
        using(var db4 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var _query2 = from c in db4.Courses
                          orderby c.Title
                          select c;

            foreach(var item in _query2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.CourseID + "     " + item.Title);
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddCourseToStudent()
    {
        using(var db5 = new MyDbContext())
        {
            var _registeration1 = new StudentCourse { StudentID = 7, CourseID = 6};
            db5.StudentCourses.Add(_registeration1);

            var _registeration2 = new StudentCourse { StudentID = 7, CourseID = 8 };
            db5.StudentCourses.Add(_registeration2);

            var _registeration3 = new StudentCourse { StudentID = 7, CourseID = 9 };
            db5.StudentCourses.Add(_registeration3);

            db5.SaveChanges();

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Those are 2 different technologies.  The API is something that you program against where the API takes data, does it's thing and returns a result.  This raw result is not something that an end user is going to want to see as it is usually in JSON or XML.  Your MVC app is a user facing app that the user interacts with.  You can make calls to your API using AJAX with CORS enabled but if you are combining the MVC and API into one project then you will be better off extracting the code to a common library so you can call it directly without having to go through your API.  The reason you can combine the 2 technologies into one project is mainly for the simple reasons that you can host them side by side on the same server, talking to the same database, using the same URL.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, you would use WebAPI to stand up a RESTful service to be consumed by:

1. A javascript application (such as SPA, Angular, Knockout, etc.)
2. Another web site (asp.net, third party, etc.)

Yes, you can use WebAPI and MVC together, but if you're building a pure MVC (Razor) front-end, then there's no value in building WebAPI calls. You can make your MVC methods available for any AJAX calls that need to be made.

When deciding what architecture to use, it's important to consider more factors than what's included in your question (i.e. number of users, public vs internal site, etc.).